# Read Excel Macros Programmaticly in PHP or JS or Another Language

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros, extract

How to extract macros in Excel file in PHP or JS?

I found https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/ but there is nothing about macros.

Answer (score 1):

With PHPExcel you can read the file and get the `VBAProject.bin`:

```
/**
* macrosCode : all macros code (the vbaProject.bin file, this include form, code,  etc.), null if no macro
*
* @var binary
*/
private $macrosCode;
```

You'd need [other tools](https://www.decalage.info/vba_tools) to examine the contents of the `VbaProject.bin` file.

E.g. using [officeparser.py](https://github.com/unixfreak0037/officeparser):

```
python officeparser.py macro.xlsm --extract-macros
INFO: Saving VBA code to ./ThisWorkbook.cls
INFO: Saving VBA code to ./Sheet1.cls
INFO: Saving VBA code to ./Sheet2.cls
INFO: Saving VBA code to ./Sheet3.cls
```